# how to export the wso2 user's UUID as part of JWT token?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to config a service provider of WSO Identity Server v5.7.0 in order to export the UUID & roles of a user as part of JWT token. I've done like this but only roles are exported. UUID is not shown.

local claim:**http://wso2.org/claims/userid**. mandatory claim: yes
local claim:**http://wso2.org/claims/role**. mandatory claim: yes

Steps:

1. In wso2 is admin console->main tab->locate the service provider I've created.
2. In "claim configuration", I choose "use local claim dialect"; 3. In "Requested Claims" I Add Claim URI.
3. I've add "wso2.org/claims/userid" & "wso2.org/claims/role" and both of them are marked "mandatory claim"
4. After saving it. I use **curl -u kbxx:Vyy -k -d "grant_type=password&username=youfa.mao&password=x&scope=openid" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" xxx:yyy/oauth2/token** to get the JWT token;
5. Only roles are in the token. The user UUID is not found

Comment: Please mention exact steps you have followed

Comment: Steps: 1. In wso2 is admin console->main tab->locate the service provider I've created. 2. In "claim configuration", I choose "use local claim dialect"; 3. In "Requested Claims" I Add Claim URI. 3. I've add "http://wso2.org/claims/userid" & "http://wso2.org/claims/role" and both of them are marked "mandatory claim" 4. After saving it. I use <b>curl -u kbxx:Vyy -k -d "grant_type=password&username=youfa.mao&password=x&scope=openid" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://xxx:yyy/oauth2/token</b> to get the JWT token; 5. Only roles are in the token. The user UUID is not found.

Answer (score 0):

In WSO2 Identity Server password grant type issue id_token(JWT) by adhering to OIDC core specification. In order to get a user claim in JWT you should have a mapping between wso2 claims(http://wso2.org/claims) and OIDC claims ( http://wso2.org/oidc/claim ). For role claim this mapping is already there where http://wso2.org/role map to groups claim in OIDC dialect.

Please follow below steps in addition to what you did to get userid claim in id_token(JWT)

1. Add userid to OIDC claim dialect

Dialect URI: http://wso2.org/oidc/claim
Claim URI: userid
Mapped Local Claim: http://wso2.org/claim/userid

2. From management console UI "OIDC Scopes" add userid claim to openid scope.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map wso2 claims to OIDC claims in order to achieve this. [blog](https://medium.com/@dewni.matheesha/claim-mapping-and-retrieving-end-user-information-in-wso2is-cffd5f3937ff), [blog](https://medium.com/@hasiniwitharana/openid-connect-certification-configurations-for-basic-profile-with-wso2-identity-server-e3cd511a9f37) section 6 with claim configuration will help you to understand how to add wso2 claim mappings.